# SQL checking if time within a series of timebands

Tags: sql-server, datetime, between

I want to write SQL to check if a given time (e.g. 5:24 AM) in Table A is within one of the following irregular time bands in Table B.

```
5:00 AM to 6:00 AM

7:30 AM to 9:15 AM

1:26 PM to 2:45 PM

4:00 PM to 4:59 PM

10:00 PM to 11:14 PM
```

My plan was to write this SQL statement:

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Given Time] BETWEEN [START TIME] and [END TIME] THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
END
```

But then I realized I'd need to write 5 joins--is there another way?

Sam

Comment: why would you have to write 5 joins? Is that the actual column values?

Comment: Yes, 5:00 AM, 7:30 AM, 1:26 PM, 4:00 PM, 10:00 PM are in one column (B.[START TIME]) and the end times are in another column (B.[END TIME])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [My Time Table] 
                 WHERE [Given Time] BETWEEN [START TIME] and [END TIME]) 
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a single reason for a `CASE` statement or a `JOIN`. This should suffice.

```
DECLARE @YourTime time = '05:42'

SELECT
   *
FROM 
   YourTable
WHERE
   @YourTime between [Start Time] and [End Time]
```

Or more explicitly...

```
...
WHERE 
   [Start Time] <= @YourTime 
   AND [End Time] >= @YourTime
```

Comment: Thanks--this worked but I needed the case statement to create the binary flag--needed the one join to relate @YourTime in Table A to Start/End time in Table B

Comment: I'm confused @Sam but if it worked, then you don't need a case or a join.  However, you didn't post a table B so it's hard to tell.